# VBA loop / do until

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, until-loop

I'm trying to configure data in a very specific format in order for it to be uploaded to a software.

I have a **count sheet** that has the amount of lines needed to be entered on my **upload template sheet**. The values on the **count sheet** range between **3, 5, 7, and 9.**

I want my VBA program to be able to enter values 1, 2, 3, (on 3 separate rows) on the **upload template sheet** if the value is "3" on the **count sheet**.

If the next value is "5" on the **count sheet** I want my program to be able to enter values 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 (on 5 separate rows on the upload sheet).

If a value is "9" on the **count sheet**, I want my program to enter values 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 (on 9 separate rows) and so on.

The first three values will always be 1, 2, 3, consecutively and then alternating between 2 and 3 based on the value on the count sheet.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What *specific* problem are you facing with this?  You should at least be able to make a start and post the code you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't enough details to really write anything. But here's a tutorial/example of how to access data from seperate workbooks and how to write values into cells inside a loop.

The equation you were looking for where the output row # follows the pattern `1,2,3,2,3,2,3...` is a little complicated with normal math, but it can be accomplished in programming math by using a Boolean expression as part of the equation.

```vb
Sub RowNumberer()
    Dim CountWB As Workbook
    Set CountWB = Workbooks("Your Count Sheet Workbook's Name (plus file extension)")
    
    Dim CountSheet As Worksheet
    Set CountSheet = CountWB.Worksheets("Your Count Sheet's Name")
    
    Dim CountSheetValue As Long
    CountSheetValue = CountSheet.Range("Cell Address of your Count result (3, 5, 7, 9)")
    
    Dim UploadWB As Workbook
    Set UploadWB = Workbooks("Your Upload Template Workbook's Name (plus file extension)")
    
    Dim OutputSheet As Worksheet
    Set OutputSheet = UploadWB.Sheets("The Name of the Sheet you want to number the rows on")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To CountSheetValue
        OutputSheet.Cells(i, 1) = i Mod 2 - 2 * (i > 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

To explain the formula: `i Mod 2 - 2 * (i > 1)`

`i Mod 2` is taking the iterating value `i` and retrieving the remainder after dividing by 2. This alternates between 1 and 0.

We would just need `+2` in order to move that from `1 and 0` to `3 and 2`. But we only want `+2` *after* the first number since we want the first number to be 1.

So I added the boolean expression `(i > 1)` which is 0 when False and -1 when True. I don't know why True = -1 in VBA. So the term `- 2 * (i > 1)` is 0 when `i = 1` and `+2` when `i > 1`.

Comment: As a thought experiment, the regular mathematical equation to get this pattern would be  `2.5 - 0.5 * (-1) ^ x - 2 * 0 ^ (x - 1)` As { x ∈ ℤ ∣ x > 0 }. This equation makes use of exponents to alternate between 2 and 3 by subtracting or adding 0.5 and another term to subtract 2 when `x=1`

Comment: Thank you SO much! This does exactly what I want it to do, now I just need to loop it down the count sheet.